# Correct pattern for managing a shared resource across multiple "flows"

Tags: .net, multithreading, design-patterns

I'm try to get a program flow that allows multiple processes to be started. Each step (activity) of a process can optionally be modal.

If a process attempts to begin a modal activity while another modal activity is running, it should be queued.

I can envisage having a `ProcessManager` that holds references to processes and (possibly) handles the "modal" resource/queueing.

But how should I wire up the processes and activities? Each process needs to be able to signal when it's about to enter a modal state and wait until granted access.

Should I pass a thread-safe callback method/object to each process or is there a better way of doing this?

Note that I won't always want to block the thread on the queued processes - The process may subsequently decide it no longer needs the modal activity and can then resume processing.

Comment: That sounds a bit odd. Asynchonous modal == synchonous ??

Comment: In short, the "modal" bit is interacting with the user. Each process does a lot of background work but occasionally needs input from the user. If one process is already interacting with the user, the next should wait until it's finished.

Comment: Can't you ask user up front, create rules and then infer without asking user again?

Comment: No, because -eg- one user interaction is required when a process receives a new item from a webservice. That said, I think we're getting little off-topic. I'm after the correct way to share a single resource between multiple threads without blocking.

Comment: In general, if changes are being made to the shared resource, you can't...........And there's nothing wrong with going off-topic if it's soliciting information that might help answer the question.

Comment: Surely, at the very worst end of the scale, I could do `New Process with {.CallBack = Function() GetModalLockCallBack()}` Where GetModalLockCallBack is thread-safe and returns a boolean indicating whether a lock was obtained (perhaps by doing an Interlocked Increment on a lock counter). This feels about as nasty as it can get but it should work. Surely there must be a more elegant solution?

Comment: And to clarify, the resource in this case is the right to interact with the user. The concrete object representing that should never need to be modified (or even have methods?)